# how to get my followers on twitter with API

Tags: php, twitter

How to get? i'm try and running this code no work,

this is my simple code and this code not work

```
include_once('twitteroauth.php');
$consumerkey = "xxx";
    $consumersecret = "xxx";
    $accesstoken = "xx";
    $accesstokensecret = "xx";

    function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
      $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
      return $connection;
    }

    $connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

    $result = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json?screen_name=keanei&count=100");
    // create an array to store the retrieved followers
    $newFollowers = array();

    foreach ($result->users as $follower) {
        $id = $follower->id;
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($follower->name);
        $screen_name = mysql_real_escape_string($follower->screen_name);
        $newFollowers[$id] = array('screen_name'=>$screen_name, 'username'=>$name);
        echo"$screen_name";
    }
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Why are you escaping strings using : `mysql_real_escape_string` ?

Comment: yeah, Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: `var_dump` the result and see the response.